# Primes less than an integer

Tags: c

I wrote a program to find all primes less that a user-input integer. However, it just hangs. I assume using all these continues and whatnot is a mess and I have made spaghetti code...can anyone help me?

```
 /*takes integer input, displays all primes less than that integer*/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int num_in, test_num = 0, divisor = 0;
    _Bool primestate = 0;
    printf("Please enter an integer.\n");
    scanf("%d", &num_in);

    while(test_num < num_in) {
        while(divisor < test_num) {
            if(test_num % divisor == 0) {
                primestate = 1;
            }

            test_num++;
        }
        if(primestate == 1) {
            printf("%d is prime and less than %d.\n", test_num, num_in);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you never increment `test_num`.

Comment: Structure your code in functions. Design each function to achieve one single purpose. Your code will naturally become clearer and easier to debug.

Comment: I keep telling myself functions are good, but never do use them. They seem like sooooooooooooooooooooo much work

Comment: `while(divisor < test_num) {` : `while(0<0){` always fail. `if (primestate == 0) { continue;`

Comment: Did you even try debugging that yourself? You know, run it under debugger step by step (with small integer), or add debug prints.

Comment: `divisor = 0;` ... `test_num % divisor` invalid(Division by zero).

Comment: Another thing, just as a hint: if user input is not a number, your code will happily proceed with undefined value in `num_in`. *Always* check return value of `scanf`...

Comment: @hyde I don't know the first thing about debugging with gdb or anything

Comment: @user3813418 If learning to use a debugger is not possible for you right now, then try adding debug prints... Such as `printf("line %d: num_in=%d\n", __LINE__, num_in);` and so on, so you can follow what your program does.

Comment: Hmm, also, why do you talk about multiple `continue`s, when your code seems to have just one? Also, that `continue` is the last thing inside the loop, so you could as well remove it, it has no effect (or, what effect do you think it has?).

Comment: I'd like to learn to use gdb, but I have not found a good guide on how to use it.

Comment: @user3813418 Well, "gdb tutorial" seems to get lot of Google hits, and Youtube seems to have many tutorial videos too... Or, install something like *Qt Creator* (don't mind the name, it's a fine C IDE too) or *Code::Blocks* or whatever other IDE which has a nice GUI debugger (which really are just frontends to plain *gdb*, so learning *gdb* is not a bad option even with these around).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int num_in, test_num, divisor;
    bool primestate;
    printf("Please enter an integer.\n");
    scanf("%u", &num_in);

    if(2 < num_in)
        printf("\n%u\n", 2);
    for(test_num = 3; test_num < num_in; test_num += 2){
        primestate = true;
        for(divisor=3; divisor * divisor <= test_num ; divisor += 2) {
            if(test_num % divisor == 0) {
                primestate = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(primestate) {
            printf("%u\n", test_num);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You never increment `test_num` or `divisor`, so it gets stuck in one of the loops.

```
while(test_num < num_in) {
    while(divisor < test_num) {
        if(test_num % divisor == 0) {
            primestate = 1;
        }
        divisor++; // NEW LINE            
    }

    if(primestate == 1) {
        printf("%d is prime and less than %d.\n", test_num, num_in);
    } else {
        continue;
    }

    test_num++; // NEW LINE
}
```

You also have a possible division by 0 (when `divisor` equals 0) on this line:

```
if(test_num % divisor == 0) {
```

Comment: Even fixing this it hangs after input. Updating code

Comment: @user3813418 Just noticed you don't increment `divisor` either. Updated code.

Comment: @user3813418 Just checked your code, you didn't increment `test_num` in the right place. Please check out my code.

Comment: I seriously goofed on this. Still hangs, and all of these `continue`s make it impossible to follow

Comment: @user3813418 Try printing out the value of test_num or divisor, to make sure the values are correct, that the program is still running.